# expression for Remainder in Taylor theorem for complex variables

Tags: complex-analysis, taylor-expansion

I don't understand how the following summation vanishes with $j=k+1$ in [wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor%27s_theorem#Taylor.27s_theorem_in_complex_analysis) .$$R_k(z) = \sum_{j=k+1}^\infty  \frac{(z-c)^j}{2\pi i} \int_\gamma \frac{f(w)}{(w-c)^{j+1}}dw
= \frac{(z-c)^{k+1}}{2\pi i} \int_\gamma \frac{f(w)dw}{(w-c)^{k+1}(w-z)} , \qquad z\in W.$$

Can anyone explain it to me? Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The second equality follows by summing infinite geometric series
$$\sum_{j=k+1}^{\infty}\left(\frac{z-c}{w-c}\right)^j=\frac{\left(\frac{z-c}{w-c}\right)^{k+1}}{1-\frac{z-c}{w-c}}=\frac{(z-c)^{k+1}}{(w-c)^k(w-z)}.$$

(Just in case: $\sum_{n=N}^{\infty}q^n=\frac{q^N}{1-q}$ for $|q|<1$, which is true in your case since $z\in W$.)

Comment: there is $f(w) dw$ to take care of .. what about it?

Comment: hmm ... i see!! thanks!!